# Javascript: How to pass php date to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How do I pass php variable from mysql to javascript ? 
`todate` from mysql is a date

eg. 2017-08-08. Below is my code.

```
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
 echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id='" data-cfromDate='" . $fromDateFinal ."' data-ctoDate='" .$row['toDate'] ."'>
 }

 var fromDate = $(this).data("cfromDate");
 console.log(fromDate);
```

The console output is: **undefined**.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo seems to be missing one quote `'` after `id`, below is the updated:

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id='' data-cfromDate='" . $fromDateFinal ."' data-ctoDate='" .$row['toDate'] ."'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML DOM Structure is not correct use the below

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-info' id=''  data-cfromDate=""'" . $fromDateFinal ."'"" data-ctoDate=""'" .$row['toDate'] ."'"">";
```